# High cpu usage spikes from one core - happens only after suspending laptop

Tags: xorg, suspend, laptop, gnome-shell, cpu-load

I got an HP pavilion laptop, specs:

Intel i7 8th

16gb ram

512gb ssd

nvidia geforce gtx 1050 3gb

I recently installed ubuntu 20.04 on it, got the nvidia drivers installed and configured correctly.

CPU usage is working fine, but when I suspend my laptop(by closing lid or clocking suspend), it sleeps, and when I turn it back on the laptop begin to have several problems:

- lags, high cpu usage spikes from one core making fans work more and battery decrease faster and even turning off the laptop gets stuck on black screen with small (_).

I checked with htop, the spikes always come from gnome-shell and Xorg && gdm/run/Xauthority.

-- I tried moving to lightdm from gdm3, also forth and back, did not work.
What works for me (sometimes) is turning off the laptop physically with the power button.

One more thing, that when I log in to my laptop after typing my password, the laptop goes black from some seconds (like a lag) and then turn on the desktop screen (maybe it's related).

**I saw that a bit similar question was asked before but it was not solved. Thank you for your help.